# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on a websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, java-websocket

I'm trying to mod a game but the websocket says name not resolved even though it looks like it should work. Can someone tell me the problem?

```
function doit() {
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="messageDisplay"></div>';
messageDisplay = document.getElementById("messageDisplay");

y = E.getElementById("canvas");
a = y.getContext("2d");
try {
    A.top.location.origin != A.location.origin && ba()
} catch (f) {
    ba()
} 
y.onmousemove = ua;
y.onmousedown = va;
y.onmouseup = xa;
M = E.getElementById("noCursorLock");
H = E.getElementById("noDrawings");
null != localStorage && (M.checked = "1" == A.localStorage.getItem("noCursorLock") ? !0 : !1, H.checked = "1" == A.localStorage.getItem("noDrawings") ? !0 : !1);
A.onbeforeunload = ya;
y.requestPointerLock = y.requestPointerLock || y.mozRequestPointerLock || y.webkitRequestPointerLock;
y.style.cursor = "none";
La();
//________________
//the main issue V
    D || null == u && (u = new WebSocket("ws://s1.cursors.io:443/"), u.binaryType = "arraybuffer", u.onopen = Aa, u.onmessage = Ga, u.onclose =
        Ba, u.onerror = Ca);
//______________
setInterval(Q, 50);
setInterval(Ja, 40);
A.requestAnimationFrame(ma)

document.onkeypress = handleKeyboard;
}
```

by the way, I didn't make this, I just want to fix it.

edit: the error is an error in connection establishment

EDIT 2:So the problem above was fixed but a new one arose. i replaced `s1.cursors.io` with `104.27.159.114` but it says `VM20349:1898 WebSocket connection to 'ws://104.27.159.114:443/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400` what is wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

It says the name is not resolved, and so it isn't.

```
%  host s1.cursors.io
Host s1.cursors.io not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

DNS doesn't hold a record for the hostname you are trying to connect to.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Connect to something that exists. So either set the name up in DNS or change the name to something else.

Comment: so `ws://(IP):443/`? still new to scripting